# Error when choosing custom style (ImageCrop) on Linux

Tags: front-end

I am getting an error message when opening the custom style window... Any ideas how to fix this?

[image: Error message: "Cropping value If[394<{400.,401.053},Left,Right] is not one of Center, Left, Right, Top, or Bottom"]

Comment: If this problem is consistently reproducible, you should contact Wolfram Support, and show them the exact steps to reproduce it. I do not see this issue in M12.3.

Comment: You can give this a try: https://support.wolfram.com/12464